# Feathersjs hook error always returns a 500 error and html body

Tags: feathersjs

I am using a before hook function to validate some query parameters. The problem is that when I throw a new error I always receive a 500 error code and an HTML body as follows, not a 400 as expected:

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvywj.png)

My hook function is the following:

```
const errors = require('@feathersjs/errors');
function validateFindQueryParameters(options){
  return context => {
    const c = {...context};
    const q = c.params.query;

    if(!q.hasOwnProperty("ticketStatus") || q.ticketStatus === ""){
      throw new errors.BadRequest('ticketStatus is not present or empty');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like Express, you have to add your own error handler. You can use the `errorHandler()` that comes with the `@feathersjs/express` module as [documented here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#expresserrorhandler):

```
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');

const app = express(feathers());

// before starting the app
app.use(express.errorHandler())
```

Also see [this FAQ entry](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#why-am-i-not-getting-json-errors).

Comment: Great! I also want to note the importance of where the line is placed because I was declaring it early in my file which was giving me problems.